# Pandas read_csv loads data into the wrong columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file containing four columns. Every row in the first column contains a tweet and the second column contains the corresponding label (which is one of the letters - A/N/Q/S - representing Actionable/Non-Actionable/Query/Suggestion respectively). So the second column basically contains the target class.

The third and fourth columns are not of relevance yet.

I am implementing the Decision Tree Classifier.

The problem is that the classifier is also treating some of the tweets as labels. So in the predicted output, while I should have been getting only A, N, Q, or S, I am also getting some tweets along with these labels.

**Following is the classifier code**: `dtree_csv.py`

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

try:
    df = pd.read_csv('tweet-class1.csv', header=None, sep=',',names=['tweets', 'class', 'dept', 'reply'],encoding='UTF-7',skipinitialspace=True)   # columns names if no header

    vect = TfidfVectorizer()
    x = vect.fit_transform(df['tweets'].values.astype('U')) 
    y = df['class']

    SIZE=50
    STEP=.02

    train,test,train_lab,test_lab=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=.15,random_state=100)

    clf=DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf.fit(train,train_lab)

    output = clf.predict(test)
    for row in output:
        print row
    print accuracy_score(test_lab,output)

except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
    print 'unicode error'
```

On running `dtree_csv.py`, this is the output I can see on the Terminal.

[image: Screenshot of the output]

I have tried a LOT of things:

- Using different combinations of separators and delimiters
- Using TSV instead of CSV
- Re-importing the original .xls file into CSV
- Switching the encoding between UTF-7 and UTF-8
- Manually scanning the CSV file for erroneous tweets

Nothing seems to work. Kindly let me know what am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll venture a guess and say that some of your tweets contain commas, and `pandas` incorrectly segments those entries into the wrong columns.

A few things you could do

1. remove all such columns using a filter and `df.isin`

   ```
   df = df[df['class'].isin(['A', 'N', 'Q', 'S'])]
   ```
2. remove extraneous `NaN` rows with

   ```
   df.dropna(inplace=True)
   ```

The alternative would be to manually change the delimiters in your CSV, or clean the offending tweets in question. If you can afford to lose some data, you should probably just drop it.

Answer (score 5):

Same kind of problem happened to me when I tried to read CSV file with commas at the end of each line.

Try to pass extra index_col=False parameter to your pd.read_csv function call.